# Knowing my Gmail for Work status

Tags: google-apps-email

Can anyone track my information from my Gmail account?

My Gmail account is controlled by an administrative department. I want to know whether they can see my messages without my permission or my password.

Answer (score 1):

Not anyone, only the administrators of Google Apps for Work of your organization could track the activity and could have access to information of you Gmail for Work account.

---

**References**
[Data access by your administrator or service provider - Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/181692?hl=en)